# Report - SQL group by week number and year

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table `temperatures` with columns `mac_address` varchar(255), `tm` datetime,
`temperature` float.
I'd like to create a report with 3 parameters: `mac_address`, `week_number` and `year`.

The report should show `maximum temperature` on certain `mac_address` in certain `week_number` (01, ... 50, ...) in certain `year`. There may be more than 1 rows for certain `week_number` and `year`...

The SQL Query for the dataset could be something like

```
select max(temperature), mac_address, tm
from temperatures
group by mac_address
having mac_address = @mac_address and week_number = @week_number and year = @year
```

Do you know how to construct the query correctly? Maybe I will need 3 more datasets.
For @mac_address parameter it is easy. I will

```
select distinct mac_address from temperatures
```

But how can I do it with @week_number and @year parameters? Is the only option to add the values for dropdown list manually?

The possible result may be:
When the user select from the parameters
`mac_address` 001, `week_number` 47 and `year` 2019

```
max_temperature | tm
27.8              t1
27.8              t2
27.8              t3
```

Now it returns 3 rows. Most of the time there will be only one row.

Comment: Why are you using a `HAVING` here and not a `WHERE`? Also, `tm` isn't in `GROUP BY` so you'll be getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you want to dynamically search by `weeknumber`, `mac_address` and `year` returning the highest temperature for each day matching in that range. A query like the following should do what you are after.

```
declare @macaddress varchar(255) = '2', @WeekNumber int = 36, @year int = 2019

Select 
  Date = tm,
  Temperature = max(temperature)
from 
  Temps t
where 
  year(tm)=@year 
  and mac_address=@macaddress 
  and datepart(week,tm) = @WeekNumber
 group by
   tm
```

If you want the mac_address included in the results, simply add to the Select and Group By sections.

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a69d7/14/0) with a test setup.

Comment: Thank you, and would you know the default values for year and week_number as current week and current year yet?

Comment: I tried the query, but it shows all temperatures. I would like it to show only max temperatures.

Comment: I tried group by year (tm), datepart(week, tm) but it does not work.

Comment: Hi, this works as expected in the SQL fiddle. Have a look there.

Comment: I would rank the temperatures, and select the times with the max temp. Working with @RyanWildry fiddle, try this query:   
`select
  mac_address,
  tm,
  temperature
from
(
Select 
  tm,
  temperature,
  mac_address,
  dense_rank() over (order by temperature desc) rn
from 
  Temps t
where 
  year(tm)=@year 
  and mac_address=@macaddress 
  and datepart(week,tm) = @WeekNumber
) tmp
where rn=1`

Comment: @SørenKongstad Thank you, it works. And please, would you know the default values for year and week_number to be current week and curret year yet?

Answer (score 1):

For a data set to build the year parameter you could use something like this, which will get you 10 years. You can expand as needed:

```
;WITH years AS (

    SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(YY,-5,GETDATE())) AS yr

    UNION ALL

    SELECT yr + 1
    FROM years
    WHERE yr < YEAR(DATEADD(YY,5,GETDATE()))

)

SELECT *
FROM years
```

For the weeks parameter you could hard-code them or use something like:

```
;WITH weeks AS (

    SELECT 1 AS wk

    UNION ALL

    SELECT wk + 1
    FROM weeks
    WHERE wk < 52

)

SELECT *
FROM weeks
```

In your main SQL data set you would want to use something like:

```
select max(temperature), mac_address, tm
from temperatures
where mac_address = @mac_address 
  and week_number = @week_number 
  and year = @year
group by mac_address, tm
```

**Edit**: remove `tm` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`

```
select max(temperature), mac_address
from temperatures
where mac_address = @mac_address 
  and week_number = @week_number 
  and year = @year
group by mac_address
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm actually strunggling now with that `something like`. Are there some functions for it to parse it from `tm`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you can add some more examples to your question then I can take a look.

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: Do you even need `tm` in your results? See **edit**... If you can't remove `tm`, what purpose does it serve? i.e. what record would you expect the query to return? `t1`, `t2`, or `t3`?

Comment: Yes, we need to see the datetimes at which max temperature occurred. Other thing is that week_number and year should be somehow parsed from tm (I don't have week_number and year in the data table)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, without your answer the accepted answer wouldn'tbe complete.